# update more than one value in parameter file using batch script

Tags: batch-file

i have one property file where i need to update the more than one value in property file using batch . i have using the script

---

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
call %~dp0\Batchenv.bat

SET sourcedir=C:\Users\1026478\Desktop\local
(
    FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%sourcedir%\test.Property") DO (
        FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%g IN ("%%a") DO (
            IF /i "%%g"=="INSTALL_PROD" (ECHO(%%g=%INSTALL_PROD%
            ) ELSE (ECHO(%%a)
        )
    )
)>newfile.property
:: newfile.txt now contains a modified version.
:: This line will overwrite the original

MOVE /y newfile.Property "%sourcedir%\test.Property"

GOTO :EOF
```

---

but this script only update one value in property file.. i need to update more than one value .

my property file like

test.property

---

```
I2_JDK_HOME=D:\\Java8\\jdk1.8.0_181
I2_LICENSE_FILE=D:\\license\\PSA100417.lic
I2_LICENSE_FILE_LOCATION=D:\\license
I2_LICENSE_FILE_NAME=PSA100417.lic
I2_ORACLE_DRIVER=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
I2_ORACLE_HOME=D:\\Oracle64\\product\\12.1.0\\client_1
I2_ORACLE_HOST=sl1psadevdb2v.jdadelivers.com
I2_ORACLE_INFO_1=ABPPMGR
I2_ORACLE_INFO_2={E:AES}6AA9880B2F94C92CA09E7665CC4AA76B
I2_ORACLE_INFO_2_XOR=@CQQLFS
I2_ORACLE_INFO_3=PSADVDB
I2_ORACLE_INFO_4=
I2_ORACLE_JAR=D:\\Oracle64\\product\\12.1.0\\client_1\\jdbc\\lib\\ojdbc7.jar
I2_ORACLE_PORT=1521
I2_PLATFORM_HOME=
I2_WEBCLIENT_TYPE=NoWeb
I2_WEBLOGIC_BASE_APP=D:\\JDA\\JDA2017_3\\config\\JDAv2017_SEMs1\\web\\base
I2_WEBLOGIC_DOMAIN_HOME=C:\\bea\\user_projects\\domains\\mydomain
I2_WEBSPHERE_APPNAME=
I2_WEBSPHERE_APPNAME_BASE=base
I2_WEBSPHERE_CONTEXTROOT=
I2_WEBSPHERE_CONTEXTROOT_BASE=/base
I2_WEBSPHERE_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\WebSphere\\AppServer
I2_WEBSPHERE_INSTALLABLE=
I2_WEBSPHERE_NODE=
I2_WEB_SERVER_PORT=22246
INSTALLER_UI=SWING
USER_INSTALL_DIR=D:\\JDA\\JDA2017_3\\config\\JDAv2017_SEMs1
```

i need to update all the value..

can anyone pls help me on this

**[Edit /]**

The variable `INSTALL_PROD` is set in another [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) file.

Batchenv.bat:

```
echo off
SET sourcedir=C:\Users\1026478\Desktop\local
SET INSTALL_PROD=Prod
SET APPSERVER_PORT2=44444
SET /a ABPP_BRE_PATH=D:\\JDA\\JDA2017_3\\config\\JDAv2017_SEMs1\\bre
```

Comment: Start by getting rid of the gratuitous code blocks `()`.

Comment: Hi could you please expain this

Comment: Cmd.exe treats everything between the `()` characters as one line and evaluates all of the variables exactly once.  Redirect the echo statements instead.

Comment: i m not able to understand exactly.. if possible  could you pls modify the above script and paste here

Comment: Not here to write code for you.  Where is the `INSTALL_PROD` variable being set?  Read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: this variable INSTALL_PROD set in another bat file Batchenv.bat  echo off


SET sourcedir=C:\Users\1026478\Desktop\local
SET INSTALL_PROD=Prod
SET APPSERVER_PORT2=44444
SET /a ABPP_BRE_PATH=D:\\JDA\\JDA2017_3\\config\\JDAv2017_SEMs1\\bre

Comment: There is an error on the last line of `Batchenv.bat`. Please remove `/a`.

Answer (score 0):

The information you wish to input into the new file should be Appended, not overwitten

To append Information use `>>` instead of `>`

For Example, If you wish to add the value of %%a into the file, you would:

`Echo(%%a>>newfile.property`